# Overwrite line in a file without creating the "^M" character

Tags: python, text-files, carriage-return

Say I have the python code:

```
print("1")
print("2")
print("3")
print("go")
```

which would produce the result:

```
1
2
3
go
```

If I wanted to overwrite the last line printed, I would do something like:

```
print("\rJohn Cena")
```

This would print to the console,

```
1
2
3
John Cena
```

However, If I piped that output to a text file using `>`, the text file would show as

```
1
2
3
go^MJohn Cena
```

How would I go about overwriting the previous line of text with a print statement, so that the output in the text file would match the output to the console?

Comment: Can you use file in ?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to re-write lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to re-write the file (i.e. read it in, replace the line, and write it back out).  Alternatively, you could just store what you want to write to the file (e.g. as a list), modify that as needed, and then write when you're done.

You could also consider writing in chunks: storing sections at a time while they are still changing, then writing them out at once (e.g. blocks of 10 or 100 lines).

Comment: Its a pretty big file, I think that would be too time-intensive. I read something about VT100 terminal controls, but I couldn't get that to work like I wanted it to...

Comment: @johnsmith101 how big? From your comment on Antti Haapala's answer, I am tempted to wonder how big can the output of BFS on an MST can be.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ I'd be reading in a file of up to 10 million vertices and edges, so If i had to read every line again, I'd guess that it would increase my runtime from 1 min to 2 min or so. Not huge, but longer than I would like